# Having a problem with cloth plane texture

Tags: texturing

[image: Flag Texture Problem]

I can't seem to figure out why the back side of the plane has these square holes in the texture.

This is a cloth simulation.

It is a single plane with the same image texture on both sides, using backfacing in shader for the backside of the plane.

It renders fine in Cycles, but I was trying to render it with Evee.
It looks like this in the Viewport and the Render.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello please pack your image and share your file, use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform